# ValueError: too many values to unpack Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, quantlib

I have the following code. However i am having error when executing same. I want the function to calculate the schedule date and ouput same to a new dataframe.
It seems the error is in the for loop. I am new to this so just trying to figure out

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Avishen\Desktop\Python\BONDDATA.xlsx')

for ISIN,issuedate,maturitydate in data:
    issueDate = ql.Date(issuedate, '%d-%m-%Y')
    maturityDate = ql.Date(maturitydate, '%d-%m-%Y')
    tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)
    day_count = ql.Thirty360
    calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
    businessConvention = ql.Unadjusted
    dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
    monthEnd = False

    # Dates in Bond Period
    df['Test']= df['t'].apply(ISIN)
    df['Test']= df['t1'].apply(ql.Schedule (issueDate, maturityDate, tenor, calendar, businessConvention,businessConvention , dateGeneration, monthEnd))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b6dc0a0bd926> in <module>
      8 
      9 
---> 10 for ISIN,issuedate,maturitydate in data:
     11     issueDate = ql.Date(issuedate, '%d-%m-%Y')
     12     maturityDate = ql.Date(maturitydate, '%d-%m-%Y')

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Desired Output

```
t       t1
Test1   Date(22,10,2019)
Test1   Date(8,2,2020)
Test1   Date(8,8,2020)
Test1   Date(8,2,2021)
Test1   Date(8,8,2021)
Test1   Date(8,2,2022)
Test1   Date(8,8,2022)
Test1   Date(8,2,2023)
Test1   Date(8,8,2023)

Test2   Date(31,7,2020)
Test2   Date(21,9,2020)
Test2   Date(21,3,2021)
Test2   Date(21,9,2021)
Test2   Date(21,3,2022)
Test2   Date(21,9,2022)
Test2   Date(21,3,2023)
Test2   Date(21,9,2023)
Test2   Date(21,3,2024)
Test2   Date(21,9,2024)
Test2   Date(21,3,2025)
```

Comment: hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you are wanting to do is to modify a dataframe row by row  (if there is more to it there may be a better solution) :

```
df['new_issueDate'] = df['issuedate'].apply(lambda row: ql.Date(row, '%d-%m-%Y')
df['new_maturityDate'] = df['maturityDate'].apply(lambda row: ql.Date(row, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

EDIT : You just want to iterate through the rows :

```
t_list = []
t1_list = []
for _, row in data.iterrows():
    issueDate = ql.Date(row['issuedate'], '%d-%m-%Y')
    maturityDate = ql.Date(row['maturitydate'], '%d-%m-%Y')
    tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)
    day_count = ql.Thirty360
    calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
    businessConvention = ql.Unadjusted
    dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
    monthEnd = False
    t_list.append(row['ISIN'])
    t1_list.append(ql.Schedule(issueDate, maturityDate, tenor, calendar, businessConvention, businessConvention, dateGeneration, monthEnd))

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'t':t_list, 't1':t1_list})
```

There's other ways to append to a dataframe row by row but this way is also fine.

Comment: I want to calculate the schedule date from the existing dataframe and output to a new df

Comment: Ok will edit the original question and provide the full code. Thanks for highlighting @Parfait

Comment: Can anyone help. Thank you

Comment: I've changed my answer, it should respond to your question

Comment: Thanks @jeed. Getting error
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'t':t_list', 't1':t1_list})
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yeah sorry there was a random apostrophe

Comment: ~~~
File "<ipython-input-48-df9fd325e27d>", line 23
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({'t':t_list, 't1':t1_list})
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
~~~
@jeed. No need to apologies. But is seems the issue is more with the "new_df". I am not able to share a pic in the comment to better explain the issue.

Comment: and a missing bracket.. my fault, I can't run so can't test.

Comment: . Thanks. t1_list is being output in 1 cell. Can it be output in different rows  group by t_list.